# Continuity of seminorms

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

The following is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_convex_topological_vector_space#Definition_via_seminorms):

> A locally convex space is defined to be a vector space $V$ along with a family of seminorms $\{p_α\}_{α ∈ A}$ on $V$.
>
> A locally convex space carries a natural topology induced by the seminorms. By definition, it is the coarsest topology for which all the mappings
>   $$
> {\begin{cases}p_{\alpha ,y}:V\to \mathbf {R} \\x\mapsto p_{\alpha }(x-y)&y\in V,\alpha \in A\end{cases}}$$
>   are continuous. A base of neighborhoods of $y$ for this topology is obtained in the following way: for every finite subset $B$ of $A$ and every $ε > 0$, let
>   $$
> U_{B,\varepsilon }(y)=\{x\in V:p_{\alpha }(x-y)<\varepsilon \ \forall \alpha \in B\}.
> $$

Denote this topology as $\tau$. The function $f:=p_{\alpha,0}:V\to\mathbf{R}$ is continuous with respect to $\tau$. Could anyone explain why
$$
f^{-1}(C)\in\tau
$$
where $C=(1,2)$? ([Edit: Thanks to @silvascientist, I just asked a silly question. What I really want to know is how $f^{-1}(C)$ contains a basic set defined above.])

---

[Some thoughts:]
When $C=(-\infty,r)$ for some $r\in\mathbf{R}$, I can see that $f^{-1}(C)\in\tau$. 
But I don't see how this might help.

Comment: clarification: what do you mean by $p_{\alpha, y}$? As in, what is the difference from $p_\alpha$?

Comment: @silvascientist: the definition of $p_{\alpha,y}$ is in the fifth line.

Comment: Ah, I see.                        .................

Answer (score 0):

Demanding that the seminorms $p_\alpha = p_{\alpha,0}$ be continuous provides us with a basis of neighborhoods of $0$, namely, the open semiballs $U_{\alpha, \varepsilon}(0)$, which are preimages of the open intervals $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ under the seminorms $p_\alpha$, and finite intersections thereof. (Although this doesn't completely ensure continuity of $p_\alpha$ since we still have to take pre-images of other basis sets in $\mathbb R$, not just basis neighborhoods of $0$, but we'll get to that in just a moment.) We can then turn this into a topology compatible with the vector space structure by translating neighborhoods of $0$ to arbitrary points, i.e, we obtain a neighborhood of $y$ by taking $U_{\alpha,\varepsilon}(0) + y = U_{\alpha,\varepsilon}(y)$. (Now we have that $p_\alpha$ is continuous - if we take any point $x \in V$, then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we can take $U = U_{\alpha,\varepsilon}(x)$ to be a neighborhood of $x$ such that $p_\alpha(U) \subseteq (p_\alpha(x) - \varepsilon, p_\alpha(x) + \varepsilon)$. This also ensures that all the $p_{\alpha,y}$  are continuous, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Now you're basis sets $U_{B,\varepsilon}(y)$ can be seen to be precisely the finite intersections of $U_{\alpha,\varepsilon}(y)$ mentioned above, and so are the basis we seek. This demonstrates that any open set in $V$ must then contain one of these sets, in particular the set $f^{-1}((1,2))$ you mention above, which must be open by continuity of $f$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: What is $p$ in the fifth line?

Comment: Corrected. It is $p_\alpha$.

Comment: By the triangle inequality of $p_\alpha$, one has "$\subset$" in the identity of the 6th line. How do you get $\supset$?

Comment: I see you've raised a critical issue in my argument. Please allow me some time while I address that.

Comment: The point is that we want the open semiballs $U_{\alpha,\varepsilon}(y)$ to form a basis for the topology, and the minimal topology such that the mappings $p_{\alpha,y}$ be continuous is precisely the topology generated by that basis. I just need to incorporate some sort of proof of that in my answer...

Comment: There. I have completely revised my answer. I apologize for any confusion I may have caused.

Answer (score 0):

After some reflection, I realize that I'm not asking what really puzzles me. It might be too late to change the whole question. I would like to record my thoughts here. 
For the  two questions in OP,

- $f^{-1}(C)\in\tau$ by *definition* of initial topology;
- If one admits that (*) indeed gives a base for $\tau$ (which would be an instructive exercise), then by the *definition* of a base, $f^{-1}(C)$ must contain a basic set. Actually, $f^{-1}(C)$ is a union of basic sets.